# How to check GORM version of grails application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am doing some debugging on code that throws errors on certain fields during a database query, and some constructor actions of a load method.
We are setting properties manually on an object before creating an instance of a class/model, however for some reason these fields (DateCreated, DateUpdated) are returning null shortly after passing them.

We have validated that these fields are in fact NOT null up until this point, so our concern is that the GORM is deleting and attempting to replace these fields because of naming convention, and perhaps we should leave our own manual setting of these fields out, and allow GORM to manage them.

Is there are way to see which version of GORM the grails app is using, and perhaps get some understanding of how this is managing these fields, and using its own generated constructor for this object?

Answer (score 1):

Depends which version for grails you are using. Assuming you are on newer grails version. The GORM version should be specified in `gradle.properties` file inside of your grails project and it looks like this:

```
grailsVersion=3.3.2
gormVersion=6.1.8.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
```

You can also find it out from gradle dependency tree with this gradle task:

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

> We are setting properties manually on an object before creating an
>   instance of a class/model...

It isn't possible to set properties on an object before creating it.

> ...so our concern is that the GORM is deleting and attempting to
>   replace these fields because of naming convention

You haven't said what the property names are but if they are `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated`, then GORM will treat those properties specially.  If you don't want that, you can turn auto time stamping off, as shown below...

```
class Person {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp false
    }
}
```

See section 8.1.9 at http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.8/hibernate/manual/index.html#eventsAutoTimestamping.